# Find two farthest points in 2D space (Manhattan distance)

Tags: algorithm

Given a list of points in 2D space (x[i], y[i]),we need to find two farthest points (Manhattan distance).

I know the algorithm but I don't quite understand how it works.

1. Find the following points: max(x[i] + y[i]), max(-x[i] + y[i]), max(-y[i] + x[i]) and max(-x[i] - y[i]) among all i.
2. Compute the distance between every point in the list and the four points chosen during the previous step and pick the largest one.

Somebody please explain why this algorithm is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have to maximize manhattan distance, where P=(X,Y) is arbitrary *fixed* point from the set

```
MD = Abs(X - x[i]) + Abs(Y - y[i])
```

There are four cases:

1 The farthest point is left and down from P (not strictly, `x[i]<=X, y[i]<=Y`), so we can open Abs-brackets as

```
MD =  X - x[i] + Y - y[i]
```

Max value of this expression is reached when `(-x[i] - y[i])` is maximum

2 The farthest point is left and upper from P, so

```
MD =  X - x[i] - Y + y[i]
```

Max value of this expression is reached when `(-x[i] + y[i])` is maximum

The same logic is for right-upper and right-down cases.

So we can see that the farthest point for any P (belonging to the set) must be chosen from these four variants (call the extremal points).

Rephrasing:

If we choose any point P from the set, the the farthest point  from it is extremal E. But the farthest point from extremal is E1 - extremal too! (it might be P, if P is extremal).

Comment: It's correct, things may be much easier to understand if we "shift" the coordinate so `P  = (0, 0)`.

Answer (score 2):

Let `P1 = (x1, y1)` and `P2 = (x2, y2)` s.t. `d(P1, P2) = |x1-x2| + |y1-y2|` is maximal.

Let's suppose for example that `x1 >= x2` and `y1 >= y2` (the other cases are really similar, you have to use the other maximal points). Then:

```
d(P1, P2) = x1 - x2 + y1 - y2 (1)
```

Let `P3 = (x3, y3)` s.t. `x3 + y3` is maximal. Our goal is to show that `d(P3, P2) >= d(P1, P2)`.

By definition`x3 + y3 >= x1 + y1 (2)`. By (1) and (2):

- If `x3 <= x2`, then: `d(P3, P2) = x2 - x3 + y3 - y2 >= x2 - x3 + (x1 + y1 - x2) - y2 = x1 + y1 - x3 - y2 >= x1 - x2 + y1 - y2 = d(P1, P2)`
- If `y3 <= y2`: symmetric case.
- Otherwise `x3 >= x2` and `y3 >= y2`: `d(P3, P2) = x3 - x2 + y3 - y2 >= x1 - y2 + y1 - y2 = d(P1, P2)`.

Thus `d(P3, P2) >= d(P1, P2)` and `d(P3, P2) <= d(P1, P2)`, so the algorithm is correct in that case.

Geometric proof: let's translate the points so that `P2` is now `(0, 0)`. Then the diameter of the set is the distance to a point lying on a closed ball of maximal diameter. The balls with Manhattan distance are squares with sides oriented at `pi/4` angle to the coordinate axes. In that case the formula is easy to find (it only depends on which quadrant a maximal-distance point lie).

Answer (score 0):

I can't give you a super techincal or detailed answer, but intuitively, it makes sense.

The reason you find the corner points first is because the maximum manhattan distance between two points will always include a corner point. If it doesn't then it can only be equal to or smaller. This makes it so for large arrays you don't have to search through every combination and therefore your search will be much more efficient. If it helps to picture it then picture 6 points on a graph. Picture the 4 corner points, in any possible position. Then try to picture a way where the inner two points are farther apart than any of the others with a corner point. Hope this helps. I know it's not very technical.